# Postgresql query. Return all values when a parameter is null/empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very simple query that requires a string array parameter. No problem when the parameter has values, but I need to return all values when the parameter is empty.

```
select distinct departamento_nom
from dim_publicas.dt_cliente dc
where departamento_nom in (${dpto})
```

I've already tried to `coalesce` the parameter, but it only takes the first value of the string array when is not null

```
select distinct departamento_nom
from dim_publicas.dt_cliente dc
where departamento_nom in (coalesce (${dpto},departamento_nom))
```

[image: img]

Comment: adding " OR ${dpto} is null " does not work?

Comment: array_length(${dpto}) = 0 is another idea to try.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the client application is performing string substition when `${dpto}` is encountered and submitting the resulting text as the query. This is a dangerous practice because it makes the query vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. A better practice is to use bound parameters.

The following query retains the risky string substitution approach. It will return all distinct rows if `${dpto}` evaluates to an empty string. If `${dpto}` evaluates to a comma separated list of quoted values, then the query will return all distinct rows that match any of the values in the list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dc.departamento_nom
  FROM dim_publicas.dt_cliente dc
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT ARRAY[${dpto}]::text[] AS dpto) t
 WHERE cardinality(t.dpto) = 0 OR dc.departamento_nom = ANY(t.dpto);
```

The query works by converting `${dpto}` into an array of strings that is returned as a column, `dpto`, in the single row table, `t`. This single row is joined to each row of `dim_publicas.dt_cliente`.